# Using sets to determine percentage of girls not in any of the given sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Among the girls of a college,60 % read the Bichitra,50% read the Sandhani,50% read the Pubani(Names of magazines),30% read the Bichitra and Sandhani,30% read the B and P,20% read the S and P while 10% read all three.How can we find out the percentage of girls that read none?I did(tried to) it by at first arranging the info.

If I am correct ,we need to find out n((B U S U P)') .So at first I tried to find n(B U S U P).For now,let (B U S) be x.Then we have,n(x) +n(p) - n(x intersects P) equal to n(B U S U P).We now figure out n(x), which is equal to n(B)+n(S)-n(B intersects S) or 80.Putting values in the first equation,we have,130-n(x intersects P).And now I don't know where to go.A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a Venn diagram and work out from the centre.[image]

You know that $10$% are in $B\cap S\cap P$. Since $30$% are in $B\cap S$, you can fill in the light blue $20$% in the region representing $(B\cap S)\setminus P$, and in similar fashion you can fill in the other two light blue percentages. Once you have them, the brown percentages are easy, since you know the total percentages for $B,S$, and $P$. And finally you can fill in the red percentage of students reading none of the three magazines.

In this problem the diagrammatic approach is probably the easiest.

Comment: Thanks,I completely forgot that strategy of using Venn diagrams while solving it.

Comment: @rahul: You’re welcome.